# How to find Title case phrases from a passage or bunch of paragraphs

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, text-parsing

How do I parse sentence case phrases from a passage.

For example from this passage

Conan Doyle said that the character of Holmes was inspired by Dr. Joseph Bell, for whom Doyle had worked as a clerk at the Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes, Bell was noted for drawing large conclusions from the smallest observations.[1] Michael Harrison argued in a 1971 article in Ellery Queen's Mystery Magazine that the character was inspired by Wendell Scherer, a "consulting detective" in a murder case that allegedly received a great deal of newspaper attention in England in 1882.

We need to generate stuff like Conan Doyle, Holmes, Dr Joseph Bell, Wendell Scherr etc.

I would prefer a Pythonic Solution if possible

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what a sentence case phrase is? (rather than just giving examples - although giving examples is certainly useful as well)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sentence case"?

Comment: I think that the OP wants to know how to determine/parse which words should have an initial upper-case letter.

Comment: @ChrisW *I* think the OP actually wants to extract named entities...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of processing can be very tricky.  This simple code does almost the right thing:

```
for s in re.finditer(r"([A-Z][a-z]+[. ]+)+([A-Z][a-z]+)?", text):
    print s.group(0)
```

produces:

```
Conan Doyle
Holmes
Dr. Joseph Bell
Doyle
Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes
Bell
Michael Harrison
Ellery Queen
Mystery Magazine
Wendell Scherer
England
```

To include "Dr. Joseph Bell", you need to be ok with the period in the string, which allows in "Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes".

I had a similar problem: [Separating Sentences](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/separating_sentences.html).

Comment: Note it's actually a quite difficult problem to fix that "Like Holmes" error in the general case.  To the OP, do research sentence chunking and named entity extraction for more info, and check out nltk.

Comment: I did think of this solution, but landed into several false positives and missed some real cases when I tried it. An example which I missed out is we also need to look at phrases like Association of Physicians

Comment: Agree with Triptych. NLP library like NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/) should be used for Named Entity Recognition.

Answer (score 2):

The "re" approach runs out of steam very quickly. Named entity recognition is a very complicated topic, way beyond the scope of an SO answer. If you think you have a good approach to this problem, please point it at Flann O'Brien a.k.a. Myles na cGopaleen, Sukarno, Harry S. Truman, J. Edgar Hoover, J. K. Rowling, the mathematician L'Hopital, Joe di Maggio, Algernon Douglas-Montagu-Scott, and Hugo Max Graf von und zu Lerchenfeld auf Köfering und Schönberg.

**Update** Following is an "re"-based approach that finds a lot more valid cases. I still don't think that this is a good approach, though. N.B. I've asciified the Bavarian count's name in my text sample. If anyone really wants to use something like this, they should work in Unicode, and normalise whitespace at some stage (either on input or on output).

```
import re

text1 = """Conan Doyle said that the character of Holmes was inspired by Dr. Joseph Bell, for whom Doyle had worked as a clerk at the Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes, Bell was noted for drawing large conclusions from the smallest observations.[1] Michael Harrison argued in a 1971 article in Ellery Queen's Mystery Magazine that the character was inspired by Wendell Scherer, a "consulting detective" in a murder case that allegedly received a great deal of newspaper attention in England in 1882."""

text2 = """Flann O'Brien a.k.a. Myles na cGopaleen, I Zingari, Sukarno and Suharto, Harry S. Truman, J. Edgar Hoover, J. K. Rowling, the mathematician L'Hopital, Joe di Maggio, Algernon Douglas-Montagu-Scott, and Hugo Max Graf von und zu Lerchenfeld auf Koefering und Schoenberg."""

pattern1 = r"(?:[A-Z][a-z]+[. ]+)+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)?"

joiners = r"' - de la du von und zu auf van der na di il el bin binte abu etcetera".split()

pattern2 = r"""(?x)
    (?:
        (?:[ .]|\b%s\b)*
        (?:\b[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*\b)?
    )+
    """ % r'\b|\b'.join(joiners)

def get_names(pattern, text):
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        s = m.group(0).strip(" .'-")
        if s:
            yield s

for t in (text1, text2):
    print "*** text: ", t[:20], "..."
    print "=== Ned B"
    for s in re.finditer(pattern1):
        print repr(s.group(0))
    print "=== John M =="
    for name in get_names(pattern2, t):
        print repr(name)
```

Output:

```
C:\junk\so>\python26\python extract_names.py
*** text:  Conan Doyle said tha ...
=== Ned B
'Conan Doyle '
'Holmes '
'Dr. Joseph Bell'
'Doyle '
'Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes'
'Bell '
'Michael Harrison '
'Ellery Queen'
'Mystery Magazine '
'Wendell Scherer'
'England '
=== John M ==
'Conan Doyle'
'Holmes'
'Dr. Joseph Bell'
'Doyle'
'Edinburgh Royal Infirmary. Like Holmes'
'Bell'
'Michael Harrison'
'Ellery Queen'
'Mystery Magazine'
'Wendell Scherer'
'England'
*** text:  Flann O'Brien a.k.a. ...
=== Ned B
'Flann '
'Brien '
'Myles '
'Sukarno '
'Harry '
'Edgar Hoover'
'Joe '
'Algernon Douglas'
'Hugo Max Graf '
'Lerchenfeld '
'Koefering '
'Schoenberg.'
=== John M ==
"Flann O'Brien"
'Myles na cGopaleen'
'I Zingari'
'Sukarno'
'Suharto'
'Harry S. Truman'
'J. Edgar Hoover'
'J. K. Rowling'
"L'Hopital"
'Joe di Maggio'
'Algernon Douglas-Montagu-Scott'
'Hugo Max Graf von und zu Lerchenfeld auf Koefering und Schoenberg'
```